# What is meant by "Grandma Plays the Numbers"?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

There's a song in the game Fallout 4 called [Grandma Plays the Numbers](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Grandma_Plays_the_Numbers). The full lyrics can be found at that link. It was written and performed by [Wynonie Harris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wynonie_Harris) in 1949.

I'm not sure what is meant by the title. It sounds like it is probably some kind of gambling. Maybe the lottery?

If that's the case, then he's really making a big deal out of it. Was playing the lottery unseemly for old ladies in 1949?

Comment: That's crazy; I was playing Fallout 4 and I was curious about that song too, so I Google'd your title quote, and it took me straight here. I thought maybe lottery too, but why the big deal :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ["numbers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbers_game) were indeed the lottery, but this was back before the government decided to get in on the action, so it was an illegal lottery run by gangsters.

Basically, it was a common, but illegal activity, so it has a slightly naughty feel to it, like drinking during prohibition.  Many, many grandmas did in fact play the numbers.

There's a fairly lengthy section in the *Autobiography of Malcolm X* about his early criminal career as a "numbers runner."